# Is there any way to make various types of enemies?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I'm making a platformer game with unity. I need some enemies which have different kinds of patterns.

For example, there is a slime which await for player and jump toward player, a bat which flies around player, and a goblin archery which patrol and shoot toward player. There would be many more various enemies but I don't know how to effectively make and manage them.

Only way I can think about is to make one script for one type of enemy; but I think that's inefficient way and hard to manage enemies if I need (e.g. I can't make enemies array). Is there any example or sample for this kind of work?

Comment: You might want to look into Composition (i.e. applying a behaviour object to an enemy). You'll probably also need to look into Interfaces or Inheritance for different kinds of behaviour.

Comment: Inheritance makes script more comfortable, but it still make one script per one enemy ,right? I'm not sure how other people manage such things, or one script per one enemy is normal?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but I'd assume you can apply the same script to multiple game entities, or is that not the case?

Comment: You could use the same script and use the animator to make the difference

Comment: A bat is not a goblin archer and you should treat it as such. You can create a generic "enemy" script that has values such as `health`, `attack damage`, etc... but you should create a class for each enemy that implements these generic scripts.

Comment: Thanks everyone... I'll try for it!

Answer (score 3):

You could make an Enemy class that has all the stats (like speed, damage, health...), and that also has the main functionalities (like spawn, die, attack, move, jump).

You should make these values and functions as simple as possible, and then inherit that script for more specific ones (like bat or archer). You could also make some functionalities come from interfaces, whichever you prefer.

The point is that you can treat all enemies in the game as "Enemy", not having to cast classes or checking for their types.

If you don't want to make different classes for different enemies, then you could make that Enemy script have values that are seen in the editor (like switches and options), and making a system where you could create an unique enemy just by changing those values (like can he jump? how fast does he move? what are his sprites? animation controller? how much damage does he make? does he have double jump? can he fly? can he throw a pie in your face? etc..)

Comment: And just to add for OP, [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) can be used as basis for these composited enemies (whether using the first, or second approach you mention), though there's also other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Use "Behavior tree" to define deffience enemies behavior.

And Make`Health` , `PlayerMovement` ... some base component to "Combine" your enemy. those compoent also can use to player. ( you can just set deffrence paramter )

"Combine" your enemy is good solution to make diffrence enemy quickly. for example:

```
class EnemeyFactory
{
    // diffrence setting 
    public Enemy SpawnA(int enemyID ...) { ... }
    public Enemy SpawnB(int enemyID)
    {
         Model m = findM(enemyID);
         AIBehavior b = findB(enemyID);

         g = new GameObject();
         Enemy e = g.AddCompoent<Enemy>();
         g.AddCompoent<PlayerMovemt>();
         g.AddCompoent<ModelHandle>().Init(m);
         g.AddCompoent<AIBehavior>().Init(b);
         int hp = 1000;
         g.AddCompoent<Health>().Init(hp);
         //...Add what you want.

         return e;
    }
}
```